# WiFi network w/hidden issues

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, wifi-configuration

I will explain this the best I can. I am on factory (located in the US) where everything is connected with a series of wireless networks (with no internet purpose). So there is a person C that easily can view all of the networks in his smartphone and his computer, just by searching them. I will add that person C it is not a worker of the company and never been here before.

The problem is that I, person E, cannot see any of those networks in my devices, such as my smartphone and my computer. They are shown as hidden networks in my computer, and in my smartphone they even do not appear. **But I should see them as person C, very easily, like not hidden networks**. This person C is a local. Me, never been before in the USA so **I think it is a "wifi configuration" for international thing or kinda like that**.

Also, I will add that there is no MAC filtering in the factory. And about wifi channels, by using a wifi analyzer all of the networks has channels under 11, so then my wifi controller should see them.

Also my controller is Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter #2 with latest driver installed. I already tried by adding them manually, but they do not connect.

edit: my OS is windows 10 last update and my computer is an HP 15-da0xxx

Comment: WiFi country restrictions are performed on the access point side, not the client-side.  I find it hard to believe that a person can see the networks of an access point they never visited.

Comment: Yes @Ramhound person C came with his USA smartphone and all the networks did appear. I have been stuck on this problem for two days

Comment: You don't even specify your hardware or your OS.  We can only help with your computer, smartphones, are completely out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: I have hard time understanding your whole story. So it's basically like, now you two guys sit down in the factory and his devices can see (and maybe connect) to WiFi of it but yours cannot (and you can see from his or others' devices that the WiFi is on 2.4GHz channel which should be supported by your device)?

Comment: Yes @TomYan you got it perfectly

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound I added the smartphone info as an example and scope of the project. I will edit the hardware part